# AWS Presigned Url Generation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I need to implement aws presigned URL in python. but I want to make sure images are not greater than 2MB. but all new mobiles have images of around 8MB. How can I handle this? How can I compress the images without even uploading them to my server?

Comment: Do you have any code example? please check [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution.
Create a lambda function that will take images and compress them to <2MB and then uploads them to the client-side.
You have to do processing on your side also for this plus lambda function will also add cost but it's a simple solution. You won't have to upload images to your server atlest.
you can add check on frontend if image >2MB then only it will compress otherwise directly upload.